# Does Pure of Voice occur before or after Save Yourselves?

Tags: guild-wars-2

The Guardian skill [Save Yourselves](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/%22Save_Yourselves!%22) is a shout which (among other things) transfers conditions from allies onto yourself.

The Guardian trait [Pure of Voice](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Pure_of_Voice) causes all allies who are affected by a shout to convert a condition into a boon.

Let's say a Guardian is surrounded by five allies, each with one condition, and the Guardian uses Save Yourselves. Does each ally have their condition turned into a boon, or do all of the conditions get transferred to the Guardian and turn into only one boon?

Comment: Note: I can't test this as I don't have a level 60+ Guardian yet. If this hasn't been answered by the time that I reach that level, I will try to test it myself.

Comment: Really good question. 
I will be following because i have the same question. 
Also,  you can always use "Save Yourselves" + "Contemplation of Purity" to convert all the conditions you've draw from your allies to you, into boons. That would be imba !

Answer (score 2):

Actually, at the moment this won't even work and no test will be able to answer your question, since it's bugged.

> Pure of Voice
>   Does not work properly with Hold the Line! or Save Yourselves!, the shouts will fail to remove the condition almost always and will never give you the opposite boon

(Source : [Guardian Bug Compilation](https://forum-en.guildwars2.com/forum/professions/guardian/Guardian-Bugs-compilation))